# Быстрое обновление данных SQL с применением PHP

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

есть такая задача:

1. Есть массив данных (300 000 строк) с текстом примерно по 5000-8000 символов, и название строки.
2. Есть база данных MySql (версия 10.3.7-MariaDB).

Задача такова - надо обновить все эти строки в самый короткий период времени

Вроде очень просто =) но есть подводные камни:

1. таблица не имеет только один уникальный ключ, это ID статьи который нам неизвестен при обновлении в связи с этим (on duplicate key) мы уже не можем использовать
2. Проверять существование названия в цикле тоже не вариант так как это очень долго (больше чем 20мин.)

Как можно это решить это на PHP, 2 недели уже голову ломаю. После завтра сессия в институте, если не сдам это задание мне конец =(

Comment: влейте все в соседнюю таблицу, добавьте индексы. напишите один апдейт запрос, учитыващий вашу логику (не обновлять если не уникальные, или хз что там еще). или это задание по пхп? :) 20 минут это долго, или что?

Comment: но индексы по заголовку и ключ все равно добавьте, там глядишь и не 20 минут потребуется

Comment: `on duplicate` работает не только с первичным ключом, но и с любым другим уникальным ключом/индексом. Так что можете добавить уникальный ключ на название, например

Comment: К сожалению нельзя создавать таблицы, так как и менять ее архитектуру. Это задание по PHP. А если применить массивы, чтобы все запросы сохранялись в массиве а потом выполнялись пачками...

Comment: *Задача такова - надо обновить все эти строки в самый короткий период времени* Догадываюсь, что надо обновить данные в БД, а не строки  в массиве... но хотелось бы услышать это явно. В любом случае нужно массив загонять во временную таблицу, её индексировать, и затем выполнять обновление. Даже если нет возможности индексировать имеющуюся таблицу, так будет быстрее, чем бомбардировать MySQL 300к запросами. *К сожалению нельзя создавать таблицы* Временная таблица - не таблица. И да - укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Кстати, насчёт "обновить"... а что делать с теми данными из массива, для которых нет соответствия в БД? добавлять? игнорировать?

Comment: Да данные надо обновлять в БД. Версия 10.3.7-MariaDB

Comment: Добавлять - если записи не существует

Comment: Чему равен `max_allowed_packet`? теоретически можно набирать до него CTE и обновляться пачками. При дефолтных 16 Мб это получатся пакеты минимум по 2000 записей, всё не так грустно, как поштучно.

Comment: max_allowed_packet 128M

Comment: Ну... это же ж всего 20 запросов получится - вообще плюнуть и растереть.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но "CTE" это что? и как использовать в PHP?

Comment: [Common Table Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/common-table-expressions/).

Comment: Блин, как вы такие вопросы понимаете?!! Это же за гранью!

Answer (score 1):

Формируете на PHP вот такой запрос:

```sql
INSERT INTO destination (s_name, s_text)
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 'name1' s_name, 'text1' s_text
              UNION
              SELECT 'name2', 'text2'
              UNION
              SELECT 'name3', 'text3'
              -- дохрена записей
              UNION
              SELECT 'nameN', 'textN' )
SELECT s_name, s_text 
FROM cte
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE s_text = VALUES(s_text);
```

Записей из исходного массива в CTE напихиваете по максимуму, но не вылетая за пределы `max_allowed_packet`. Получится менее 20 запросов.

Если уникальный индекс по `s_name` отсутствует и не может быть создан (хотя бы временно) - придётся формировать два запроса вместо одного. Один UPDATE и один INSERT. Формирование/использование самого блока CTE от этого не изменится.

```sql
UPDATE destination, ( SELECT 'name1' s_name, 'text1' s_text
                      UNION
                      SELECT 'name2', 'text2'
                      UNION
                      SELECT 'name3', 'text3'
                      -- дохрена записей
                      UNION
                      SELECT 'nameN', 'textN' ) cte
SET destination.s_text = cte.s_text
WHERE destination.s_name = cte.s_name
```

и

```sql
INSERT INTO destination (s_name, s_text)
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 'name1' s_name, 'text1' s_text
              UNION
              SELECT 'name2', 'text2'
              UNION
              SELECT 'name3', 'text3'
              -- дохрена записей
              UNION
              SELECT 'nameN', 'textN' )
SELECT DISTINCT cte.s_name, cte.s_text 
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN destination ON destination.s_name = cte.s_name
WHERE destination.s_name IS NULL
```

Ну и само собой не забудьте заквотить служебные символы в тексте, типа кавычек и прочего.

Comment: Спасибо за наглядный пример, но вот "формировать два запроса вместо одного. Один UPDATE и один INSERT. " я не совсем понимаю - у меня пока очень слабые познания в SQL =( Пожалуйста не могли  бы вы дать еще один пример = ) спасибо.

Comment: Человек написал, что задание на пехепе. Ванга передела, что тупой препод ждет решения на пехепе, а вы хотите решить на sql. Т.е. я вам на 99% гарантирую, что там должно быть постраничное чтение файла, постраничное чтение БД, сравнение строк, формирование запросов на обновление или запись и т.д.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Дык всё это он проделает, чтобы построить запросы. А одна запись одним запросом добавляется или две тысячи - это, право, мелочи...

Answer (score 1):

Ну т.к. идет речь о задании на пехепе, то я бы предложил следующий вариант - 
читаем файл построчно(fgetcsv т.к. скорее всего формат csv) что бы не держать в памяти текст, формируем массив где ключами будут названия строк, а данными номера строк, далее выбираем данные из бд и по ключу (название строки) добавляем к данным о номере строки в файле айди из БД. Соответственно теперь мы получили массив где ключ это строка (в принципе нам больше не нужный), а данные это номер строки в файле и айди в БД. Далее нам нужно будет отсоритировать массив по номеру строк (т.к. мы будем читать файл с начала построчно) и начать спокойно формировать запросы на вставку или обновление данных. Я думаю, глупый преподаватель ждет увидеть примерно такое решение. Жаль, что топикстартер вряд ли оценит мое старание, а тем более вопротить эту тревиальную задачку в коде.

Вот как то так решил набросать -

```
$handle = fopen("data.csv", "r"))// string_name,text\r\n
$strings = [];
$collation = [];
$row = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $strings[$data[0]] = $row++; // возможно более оптимальное решение по памяти?
}
$result =mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`string_name` FROM `data`");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $collation[$strings[$data['string_name']]] = $data['id'];
}
unset($strings);
$row = 1;
rewind ($handle);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $id = $collation[$row++];
    $text = $data[1];
    if($id) {
        //  делаем обновление (формируем пакет запросов)
    } else {
       //  делаем вставку  (формируем пакет запросов)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ достаточно хорош! попробую...

Comment: Да, исходные данные предоставляются в xml. С парсингом проблем нет =) обработка 300 000 блоков за 65-70 сек.